# Is it possible to use retraining to swap Class feats for Archetype feats?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

The [Retraining](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=522) activity says about Feats -

> You can spend a week of downtime retraining to swap out one of your feats. Remove the old feat and replace it with another of the same type. For example, you could swap a skill feat for another skill feat, but not for a wizard feat.

[Archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=167) feats (Dedication and otherwise) are selected in place of Class feats, but are generally not actually Class feats (there are some exceptions that overlap, and there are possibly Class archetypes in the future). Can retraining be used to swap a Class feat for an Archetype feat, or vice versa?

The Feat retraining rule seems to say you can only swap a feat for the same type of feat, but I think this language is simply intended to prevent a character from replacing a feat with a type they would not have been able to take at that point, rather than outright mandating the feat needs to be exactly the same type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

From the rules on [archetypes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=167):

> For example, if you gained an ability at 6th level that granted you a 4th-level class feat with the dwarf trait, you could swap out that class feat only for an archetype feat of 4th level or lower with the dwarf trait. **Archetype feats you gain in place of a class feat are called archetype class feats.** (emphasis added)

Archetype feats gained by the base rules are generally **archetype class feats**, as per the quote above. Perhaps this matters for things like the [Ancient Elf Heritage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?ID=34), which provides an archetype feat without making it a class feat. There doesn't seem to be any reason to worry about retraining in the class to archetype direction, though, as those feats would become archetype class feats then.